# Failed to connect to server-need latest answer all other post were very old and not working

Tags: php, phpmailer

**Error for 465(ssl)**
2019-02-02 07:53:39 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: (0)
SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

**Error for 587:**
2019-02-02 08:00:02 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO 10.10.11.65
2019-02-02 08:00:02 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
2019-02-02 08:00:03 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
2019-02-02 08:00:03 
SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

Here is my code i am using host name with my server number EX:10.10.10.10
user name and password is my email id username and password

```
  <?php
     require("src/PHPMailer.php");
      require("src/SMTP.php");
      require("./src/Exception.php");

        $mail = new PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer();
        $mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP

        $mail->SMTPDebug = 1; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true; // authentication enabled
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for Gmail
        $mail->Host = 'xx.xx.xx.xx';  //server ip
        $mail->Port = 465; // or 587
        $mail->IsHTML(true);
        $mail->Username = "myid@domainname.com";
        $mail->Password = "CooW0rk@l#2k19";
        $mail->SetFrom("myid@domainname.com");
        $mail->Subject = "Test";
        $mail->Body = "hello";
        $mail->AddAddress("to_id@domainname.com");

         if(!$mail->Send()) {
            echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
         } else {
            echo "Message has been sent";
         }
    ?>
```

Comment: Can any one help me out

Comment: is there anyone to help me out regarding this???

Comment: nobody is here to help me out. Totally am fed up with stack overflow